# unable to decode saved info in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to save a very simple object using NSKeyedArchiver in swift, and I see that it is saving correctly, with values, but whenever it tries to decode the saved data it fails. I am new to swift and I have tried googling and os_log (ing) everything, but I can't see where the problem lies. Here is the Object I am trying to save...

```
class TrackedAmount: NSObject, NSCoding {
  var cups: Int
  var fraction: Float?

  struct PropertyKey {
    static let cups = "cups"
    static let fraction = "fraction"
  }
  init?(cups: Int, fraction: Float?) {
    os_log("Running init? function", log: .default, type: .debug)
    if(cups < 0) {
      os_log("Cups less than 0. Returning nil", log: .default, type: .debug)
      return nil
    }
    self.cups = cups
    self.fraction = fraction
  }

  required convenience init? coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    os_log("Running required convenience init? function", log: .default, type: .debug)
    guard let cups = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.cups) as? Int else {
      os_log("Unable to decode cups", log: .default, type: .debug)
      return nil
    }
    guard let fraction = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.fraction) as? Float else {
      os_log("Unable to decode fraction", log: .default, type: .debug)
      return nil
    }
    self.init(cups: cups, fraction: fraction)
  }

  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(cups, forKey: PropertyKey.cups)
    aCoder.encode(fraction, forKey: PropertyKey.fraction)
  }
```

Then in my ViewController I am trying to get and save them like so,...

```
 private func saveAmount() {
    trackedToday = TrackedAmount(cups: selectedCups, fraction: selectedFraction)
    print("data.... cups: " + String(trackedToday!.cups) + " fractions: " + String(trackedToday!.fraction!))
    let fullPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("dailytracked")
    do {
      let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: trackedToday!, requiringSecureCoding: false)
      try data.write(to: fullPath)
    } catch {
      os_log("Unable to save tracking amount", log: .default, type: .debug)
    }
  }

  private func loadDailyTracked() -> TrackedAmount? {
    let fullPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("dailytracked")
    if let nsData = NSData(contentsOf: fullPath) {
      do {
        let data = Data(referencing: nsData)
        if let loadedData = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? TrackedAmount {
          os_log("it finally worked", log: .default, type: .debug)
          return loadedData
        }
      } catch {
        os_log("Couldn't read from file", log: .default, type: .debug)
        return nil
      }
    return nil
  }
```

It is saving correctly but whenever I try to run the loadDailyTracked() method I get the following in the output section in xcode...

> Running required convenience init? function
>
> Unable to decode cups

I can't seem to figure out why it can't decode the cups, I know the data is being saved since none of the logs show any failure except for when it is trying to read from the saved data. I even logged the information before saving and it is showing the correct data. Anyone have any ideas? I am really new to IOS and Swift and I just can't figure this out. Thank you.

*Side note, if you need more code or information I am happy to provide it, I was just trying to keep the post from being too big if it didn't need to be.

Comment: you should add the path extension to your file name ".plist". it is not a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of `NSCoder` scalar types like `Int` and `Float` are **not** objects and the dedicated methods don't return optionals

```
required convenience init? coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    os_log("Running required convenience init? function", log: .default, type: .debug)
    let cups = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.cups)
    let fraction = aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: PropertyKey.fraction)
    self.init(cups: cups, fraction: fraction)
}
```

`NSCoding` in Swift is pretty heavy. It's highly recommended to use the `Codable` protocol to serialize structs and classes.

Comment: I was using the tutorial from IOS as a base to learn this, it shows them using and as? Int in the tutorial. I will try to look at the Codable protocol and see if I can figure that out. Here is the link to the tutorial I was using https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1

Comment: There is no `as? Int` in the tutorial. Only `String` and `UIImage`. The behavior of `String` is different because it's implicitly bridged to `NSString` which **is** an object. On the other hand `Int` and `Float` are not bridged to `NSNumber`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed that part. So I switched the stuff to use decodeInteger and decodeFloat and now I am getting "Couldn't read file" in the output when running the app, now all of a sudden it can't read from the file the line if let nsData = NSData(contentsOf: fullPath) are failing

Comment: As Leo mentioned in the comment you have to add a path extension. And don't use `NSData` in Swift at all. Use `Data` and put it into the `do - catch` block.

Comment: I added it. Doesn't the Data need the referencing: NSData to work? The code now shows let fullPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("dailytracked.plist") it is running through to the catch statement now, "Couldn't read file"

Comment: **Never** log meaningless literal strings like `"Couldn't read from file"` in a `catch` block, log the caught actual **error**.

Comment: is it the same as something like Java where I would do catch(Exception e) { error_log("error occurred: ", e); }

Comment: I don't speak java. In a catch block a variable `error` is available. I don't know if `log` can take an `Error` instance. If not, just `print(error)`.

Comment: I got it working using Codable like you suggested. Thank you so much!!!